# How can I implement system-specific functions without macros in modern C++

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, preprocessor, compile-time

JetBrains ReSharper for C++ has told me to replace something like

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
#    define cls system("cls")
#else // Assuming Unix
#    define cls system("tput clear")
#endif // _WIN32
```

with constexpr template functions.

However, I have tried to use SFINAE via `std::enable_if_t<_WIN32>`, but I'm getting errors saying "cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone" (admittedly, I was not using a template function, but instead using `enable_if` for the return type).

Besides using `enable_if` as the return type, I don't know how to use constexpr template functions to implement what the preprocessor would do.

In a more general sense, I would like to be able to enable function overloads based on compile-time booleans that don't rely on other template parameters.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want `enable_if`, which is for cases where you might need to make decisions at compile time based on type parameters, etc.

The preprocessor is appropriate here, though it might be cleaner to use ordinary functions than macros.

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
void cls() { system("cls"); }
#else // Assuming Unix
void cls() { system("tput clear"); }
#endif // _WIN32
```

Comment: I'd move the preprocessor bits inside the function, so that way you know every variant has the exact same signature.

Comment: `void cls() { #ifdef _WIN32 system("cls"); #else system("tput clear"); #endif }`

Comment: Another possibility, if you have enough of this stuff to make it worth your while, is to move the win32 and unix stuff into different files and only arrange your build scripts to only link in the file appropriate to the target system.